# How to extract rows (using Loop) from a data frame and save it in another data frame

Tags: r

I have 2 files (as data frames), the first one cossets of three columns lets say:

```
POS  Freq1  Freq2
23   0.5    0.45
48   0.7    0.55  
05   0.8    0.65
```

and so on..

the second file consists of 2 columns:

```
Start  End
1      10
25     50
60     75
```

and so on.
what I need to do is to extract the rows in the first line that has POS values >= Start and <=End; that is I want to check the following:

is `23 >=1 && <=10`    (False)

is `23 >=25 && <=50`   (False)

and keep checking all the values in Start and End till find a true

is `48 >= 1 && <=10`    (False)

is `48 >=25 && <=50`   (TRUE)

Stop checking the rest

is `5 >=1 && <=10`    (TRUE)

Stop checking the rest

Then all values of POS that give a true should be stored in a data frame with the rest of info in file 1: so what I want to get at the end is this (assuming that all comparisons for the first row are false)

```
POS  Freq1  Freq2
48   0.7    0.55 
5    0.8    0.65
```

I tried the following in R:

```
Trial = NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(file1) {
   for (j in 1:nrow(file2){
     if (file1$POS[[i]] >= file2$Start[[j]] & file1$POS[[i]] <= file2$End[j])  
       Trial = c(Trial,file1[i, ]) 
     else stop("Check the file Trial")
  }
}
Trial 
## $POS
## [1] 48
## $Freq1
## [1] 0.7
## $Freq2
## [1] 0.55
```

And this is not what I am after?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Downvote for formatting.

Comment: @LucasZamboulis If you edit for format, do more than just indent.  Make the code so that someone can paste the pieces directly into the R interpreter.

Comment: @hopeLo: Please see the answer below and comment whether it worked for you or not.

Comment: Thank you mso so much, it worked :) AND sorry for the formatting of my question, this is the first time I posted on StackOverflow.. will try to do better next time ;)

Comment: @hopeLo: If it worked you should click on tick and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ddf = structure(list(POS = c(23L, 48L, 5L), Freq1 = c(0.5, 0.7, 0.8
), Freq2 = c(0.45, 0.55, 0.65)), .Names = c("POS", "Freq1", "Freq2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

refdf = structure(list(Start = c(1L, 25L, 60L), End = c(10L, 50L, 75L
)), .Names = c("Start", "End"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

ddf
#  POS Freq1 Freq2
#1  23   0.5  0.45
#2  48   0.7  0.55
#3   5   0.8  0.65

refdf
#  Start End
#1     1  10
#2    25  50
#3    60  75

outdf = data.frame(POS=numeric(), Freq1=numeric(), Freq2=numeric())
for(i in 1:nrow(ddf)) for(j in 1:nrow(refdf)){
      if(ddf[i,1]>refdf[j,1] &&  ddf[i,1]<refdf[j,2])
           {outdf[nrow(outdf)+1,] = ddf[i,]; next}
}
outdf
#  POS Freq1 Freq2
#2  48   0.7  0.55
#3   5   0.8  0.65
```