# Select rows by criteria in another data.frame without for loop in R

Tags: r

This is related to question: [How to extract rows (using Loop) from a data frame and save it in another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457346/how-to-extract-raws-using-loop-from-a-data-frame-and-save-it-in-another-data-f/25457603)

If 'POS' of ddf lies between any 'start' and 'end' of refdf, it needs to be included in outdf which has same structure as ddf. I could manage it with 'for' loop, but can it be done without using 'for' loop?

```
ddf = structure(list(POS = c(23L, 48L, 5L), Freq1 = c(0.5, 0.7, 0.8
), Freq2 = c(0.45, 0.55, 0.65)), .Names = c("POS", "Freq1", "Freq2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

refdf = structure(list(Start = c(1L, 25L, 60L), End = c(10L, 50L, 75L
)), .Names = c("Start", "End"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

ddf
#  POS Freq1 Freq2
#1  23   0.5  0.45
#2  48   0.7  0.55
#3   5   0.8  0.65

refdf
#  Start End
#1     1  10
#2    25  50
#3    60  75


outdf = data.frame(POS=numeric(), Freq1=numeric(), Freq2=numeric())
for(i in 1:nrow(ddf)) for(j in 1:nrow(refdf)){
      if(ddf[i,1]>refdf[j,1] &&  ddf[i,1]<refdf[j,2])
           {outdf[nrow(outdf)+1,] = ddf[i,]; next}
}
outdf
#  POS Freq1 Freq2
#2  48   0.7  0.55
#3   5   0.8  0.65
```

I tried following but it does not work:

```
apply(ddf,1,function(x){print(x);ifelse(x[1]>refdf$Start & x[1]<refdf$End, x,"")})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't particularly efficient in space for large problems, but it doesn't use `for`:

```
ddf[ddf$POS %in% unlist(apply(refdf, 1, function(x) seq(x[1],x[2]))),]
##   POS Freq1 Freq2
## 2  48   0.7  0.55
## 3   5   0.8  0.65
```

All the allowed values of `POS` are computed by the `unlist(apply)` expression.  This of course assumes that `POS` contains only integral values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.  It doesn't necessitate integer values, but it's also not going to be especially efficient:

```
pow <- cbind(expand.grid(ddf$POS, refdf$Start), Var3=expand.grid(ddf$POS, refdf$End)$Var2)

boom <- pow[which(pow$Var1 > pow$Var2 & pow$Var1 < pow$Var3), 'Var1']

ddf[ddf$POS %in% boom, ]
#  POS Freq1 Freq2
#2  48   0.7  0.55
#3   5   0.8  0.65
```

Comment: Good and complex use of expand.grid.